# NSXMLParser won't parse in iOS 4.3 but does in 5.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, ios-simulator, nsxmlparser

I've got an interesting problem.
I have an iPad App which has to parse some XML-Data from the Web and it all works fine in 5.0 Simulator and Device but on iOS 4.3 Simulator (actually i don't have any 4.3 Device available)  it won't parse and the `[NSXMLParser parse]`  method retuns NO
I already tried downloading the string first then converting it to NSData, aswell as Dowloading the NSData directly and initialize the parser with the downloaded NSData.

Here's my Code

```
-(void)parseWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if (url != nil) {
        self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [[self parser] setDelegate:self];
        if([[self parser] parse]){
            NSLog(@"WOOHOO!");
            [TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"XML has been parsed"];
        }
}
```

The urlString has been checked and is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log the `parseError` property of your `NSXMLParser`.  That should lead you to know what exactly is your problem.

```
-(void)parseWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if (url != nil) {
        self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [[self parser] setDelegate:self];
        if([[self parser] parse]){
            NSLog(@"Parser completed.");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Parser failed. Error: %@",[self.parser parseError]);
        }
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement the following protocol and log the error that occurs during parsing:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like I've overseen the obvious. The Problem however is an encoding error (Unknown encoding) I have to solve now -.-
However I wonder why this is actually working in iOS 5

Comment: Most likely, a bug in NSXMLParser was fixed in iOS5. There were quite a few updates to that class.